Read gzip content from python request
I have some json data that I want to send over a http call with gzip compression.
[{"article_id":"42278","store_id":"3","alias":" ","name":"5d light cartoon dog","short_name":"5d light cartoon dog","description":"5d light cartoon dog","manufacturer_id":"449","allow_negative":"N","replenishment_mode":"FT","allow_purchase":true,"allow_sales":true,"created_at":"2024-03-23","min_shelf_fit":0,"preparation_type":"T"},{"article_id":"42279","store_id":"3","alias":" ","name":"5d light cute elephant","short_name":"5d light cute elephant","description":"5d light cute elephant","manufacturer_id":"449","allow_negative":"N","replenishment_mode":"FT","allow_purchase":true,"allow_sales":true,"created_at":"2024-03-23","min_shelf_fit":0,"preparation_type":"T"},{"article_id":"42280","store_id":"3","alias":" ","name":"5d light happy ponny","short_name":"5d light happy ponny","description":"5d light happy ponny","manufacturer_id":"449","allow_negative":"N","replenishment_mode":"FT","allow_purchase":true,"allow_sales":true,"created_at":"2024-03-23","min_shelf_fit":0,"preparation_type":"T"},{"article_id":"42281","store_id":"3","alias":" ","name":"5d light funny rabbit","short_name":"5d light funny rabbit","description":"5d light funny rabbit","manufacturer_id":"449","allow_negative":"N","replenishment_mode":"FT","allow_purchase":true,"allow_sales":true,"created_at":"2024-03-23","min_shelf_fit":0,"preparation_type":"T"}]


I use the gzip command to compress it to another file and then send it in a curl as this -
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:7777/master/am/' \
-H 'X-SYNC-TOKEN: all_pass' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d "@master_small.json.gz"

My python server(flask) that receives this has the endpoint as this -
@ArticleMasterController.route("/", methods=["POST"])
@swag_from("../../swagger/master/article_master.yaml")
def sync_article_master():

  uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=request.stream)

  logger.info(f"--------------------")
  logger.info(f"{uncompressed.read()}") #This fails.
  logger.info(f""--------------------")


  message = "Yet to implement"
  return jsonify({"message": message, "status": 'success'})

3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |  Traceback (most recent call last):
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/dcove/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/dcove/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/dcove/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      rv = self.dispatch_request()
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/dcove/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/envs/dcove/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flasgger/utils.py", line 305, in wrapper
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      return function(*args, **kwargs)
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/delium/retail/syncs/dcove/controller/master/article_master.py", line 18, in sync_article_master
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      uncompressed = gzip.decompress(request.data)
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 556, in decompress
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      return f.read()
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 300, in read
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      return self._buffer.read(size)
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |    File "/home/leoorion/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 506, in read
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |      raise EOFError("Compressed file ended before the "
3:16:12 PM dcove_server.1 |  EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached

What am I doing wrong here ? How do I read the gzipped json data ? This can be either streamed or read fully all at once into a file.
What else have I tried ?
gzipContent = io.BytesIO(request.data)
uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipContent, mode='rb')

gzip.decompress(request.data)

Above 2 fails with the same error.

uncompressed = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=request.data)
logger.info(uncompressed)

If I read the request.data, it prints the gzip encoded string
[am.py:21] <gzip '\x1f\x8b\x08\x08\xb0waf\xf1\x9c\x854\x9b\xd2\xdd>\xc0\x1e{\xda[)2k&Q0*:i\t\xa5\xef^-\xbb\x85\x01\x15l.\xa8\xff\xa7\xf3\xf5\xee\x0bZ\x85[I;\x05 0x7fb9eebc1f70>

Have I tested the gzip file ? Yes
In my python console, if I call gzip decompression on teh file directly with the same code samples above, it passes. It only fails when coming over http through the flask request object.
Have also decompressed it locally post the compression using the gzip command and all works well.
